# How to modify transaction behavior in EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework

In Code-First Entity Framework, is there a way to modify the transaction behavior so that it does not discard all changes and instead keep all the changes up to the point of failure?

For example:

```
foreach {var objectToSave in ArrayOfEntityObjects)
{
     MyContext.Insert(objectToSave);
}
try
{
     MyContext.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception x)
{
    //handling code
}
```

In the above example, assuming the array is an array of 100 objects and that an error occurred on item 50, I want to keep the ones that were successful, up to the point of failure at least.  Right know we are executing the MyContext.SaveChanges() command during each iteration of the foreach loop to do this, but we would like the performance boost of committing to the database in one commit (Our understanding is that EF sends all the commands at once for the transaction, over a single connection, thus only using one round trip).

Comment: No, the transaction has already been rolled back when you're made aware of the error. I would commit the changes in chunks of, say, 20-50. Reducing transaction size can sometimes be beneficial anyway.

Comment: Thanks.  That is basically what we thought.  Still hope someone knows a way though.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this automatically.  EF commits all changes in a single transaction, which means it's an all or nothing thing.

If you want this behavior, then you must save changes after each and every record you add.

The reason is that EF doesn't know what constitutes a "transaction" in your data.  It might be one row, or it might be several rows in several tables.  EF doesn't even try to understand what your transactional requirements might be.  You have to do it manually if you want it.